# percentages in SSAS Data Cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

So I have a dimension called Attendance Mark that contains strings, such as 'PRESENT'. I have a measure 'Attendance Count' that counts the total entries. I came up with this (heavily inspired by Google searching) MDX calculation to get the percentage of Attendance Mark entries that read 'PRESENT':

```
Case
  When IsEmpty ([Measures].[Attendance Count])
  Then NULL
  Else ( [Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].&[PRESENT],
    [Measures].[Attendance Count]) /
  (  [Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark],
    [Measures].[Attendance Count] )
End
```

This seems to work thought I'm not 100% confident in it, but it gets very strange results if I view that measure by the Mark dimension. As you'd expect PRESENT displays 100%, but you'd expect the others to show 0%- because there are 0 'PRESENT' values within their scope. Instead they're showing things like 865.29%, 1338.17% or 169.76%. Totally errant data.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

P.S Obviously you'd never display the percentage measure by the mark dimension in practical use anyway but I don't want it to confuse users, and it'd be useful to understand why this is happening anyway.

Comment: What do you mean with "by the Mark dimension"? Do you use A WHERE condition? A subselect? Using `Mark` on the rows or columns?

Comment: I mean using the Mark dimension on a column, which displays a column for each distinct mark and a calculation on the measures within that scope. 


The 'PRESENT' mark shows 100% as you'd expect, because within that scope they are all 'PRESENT'. But the others show weird, errant data where you'd expect 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke the problem down into three simple parts: the numerator, the denominator, and the final percentage.

The trick is that you want the calculation to respect all [PRESENT] and non-[PRESENT] members of [Attendance Mark] as well as the [All] member. So, [PRESENT] should be 100%, non-[PRESENT] should be null, and [All] should be the percentage of [PRESENT] out of the total.

```
with
    member [Measures].[x] as
        aggregate(
            exists(
                {[Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].&[PRESENT]},
                {[Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].CurrentMember}
            ), [Measures].[Attendance Count]
        )
    member [Measures].[y] as
        aggregate(
            exists(
                {[Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].CurrentMember},
                {[Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].&[PRESENT]}
            ), [Measures].[Attendance Count]
        )
    member [Measures].[z] as
        [Measures].[x] / [Measures].[y], format_string = 'Percent'
select
    {[Measures].[Attendance Count], [Measures].[x], [Measures].[y], [Measures].[z]} on 0,
    non empty [Attendance Mark].[Attendance Mark].Members on 1
from
    [cube]
```

where `[Measures].[x]` represents the numerator, `[Measures].[y]` represents the denominator, and `[Measures].[z]` represents the final percentage calculation. You can obviously do this in one single step. I broke it out for clarity.

Comment: I have no way of verifying if this is correct since the question was from so long ago, but I really appreciate the effort you put into this. Hopefully it helps the next person with this problem.